# CSS Conditionals for WebKit Browsers

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

I want to apply a CSS style for a div but I dont know how to recognize Chrome for Desktop and Android Navigator

```
.myDIV{
[if CHROME???] width: 280px; 
[if ANDROID???] width: 100%; 
}
```

Is there a way to detect chrome or android navigator from CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't check for Android (you can't in CSS) - check for the screen size using [Media Queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries). This is much better than checking for a particular named browser and is known as responsive design when used to make designs work at a range of sizes.

```
.myDiv { width: 280px; }

@media screen and (max-width: 699px) {
  .myDiv { width: 100%; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but  I think the only was is to sniff the browser agent and then add a class to the body.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Answer (score 0):

While there is not a CSS specific hack for older Androids, I found a way that will rule out iPads/iPhones (any iOS device). This does not work for older, non 'ultra high definition' devices but should work for just about any modern one now.

How you use it:

```
/* Modern Androids (For Android 4.0+, Chrome 15+, Safari 5.1+, and Opera 14+) */

_:-webkit-full-screen, :root .selector { color:blue; }
```

Test it at my live CSS hacks test page:

http://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.io/css_hacks.html#webkit OR
http://browserstrangeness.github.io/css_hacks.html#webkit

The reason this works is iOS does not support the :-webkit-full-screen CSS pseudo-class which is otherwise included in webkit distributions.

At time of this posting, Safari is in version 8, and Chrome is in Development/Canary versions up to 41.

Enjoy!