# css margin-top is not the same in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css

I have a div with this css styling as below:

```
//Search
.input-append{
    text-align:right;
    margin-left:-35px;
    height:20px;
    margin-top:-15px!important;
    input[class*="span"]{
        margin:-2px 0 0 0;
        padding:4px;
    }
    button.btn{
    height:30px;

        margin-top:-2px!important;
            i.icon-search{

                text-shadow:none;
            }
    }
}
```

I dont know why it is not appearing in same position in both browser.
In Chrome it appears the div a little bit above than Firefox, How can i make an if statement if it is a Chrome browser different margin-top or vice versa!

Thanks

Comment: You should really search before posting a question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441878/css-conditionals-for-webkit-browsers

Comment: Looking for workaround vs fixing your CSS...

Comment: Your CSS code is completely invalid. CSS cannot be nested the way you're doing it. (if you're using a CSS pre-processor like SASS or Less where nesting is allowed, please say so, but it doesn't look valid even for them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**CSS Reset**](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-1-resetting-your-styles-with-css-reset/) avoids browser inconsistencies.

So try adding the below css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Read more about [**Eric Meyer's Reset CSS Tools**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: I imagine that OP has done a lot of work without using Reset, so this will end up moving too much

Comment: @danrhul Yup.  But we can suggest good ideas, so he can learn something right?

Comment: It was more to warn OP, it is, of course, a good idea to use reset or similar